# BeautifulSoup: Get text, create dictionary

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping information on central bank research publications, So far, for the Federal Reserve, I've the following Python code:

```
START_URL = 'https://ideas.repec.org/s/fip/fedgfe.html'
page = requests.get(START_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
for paper in soup.findAll("li",class_="list-group-item downfree"):
    print(paper.text)
```

This produces the following for the first, of many, publications:

> 2018-070 Reliably Computing Nonlinear Dynamic Stochastic Model
>   Solutions: An Algorithm with Error Formulasby Gary S. Anderson

I now want to convert this into a Python dictionary, which will eventually contain a large number of papers:

```
Papers = {
  'Date': 2018 - 070,
  'Title': 'Reliably Computing Nonlinear Dynamic Stochastic Model Solutions: An Algorithm with Error Formulas',
  'Author/s': 'Gary S. Anderson'
  }
```

Comment: Don't use "code snippet" for Python code. See the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) that is available while entering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get good results extracting all the descendants and pick only those that are [NavigableStrings](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring). Make sure to import *NavigableString* from bs4. I also use a numpy list comprehension but you could use for-loops as well.

```
START_URL = 'https://ideas.repec.org/s/fip/fedgfe.html'
page = requests.get(START_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

papers = []
for paper in soup.findAll("li",class_="list-group-item downfree"):
    info = [desc.strip() for desc in paper.descendants if type(desc) == NavigableString]
    papers.append({'Date': info[0], 'Title': info[1], 'Author': info[3]})

print(papers[1])

{'Date': '2018-069',
 'Title': 'The Effect of Common Ownership on Profits : Evidence From the U.S. Banking Industry',
 'Author': 'Jacob P. Gramlich & Serafin J. Grundl'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to match each part of string.

- `[-\d]+` the string only have number and `-`
- `(?<=\s).*?(?=by)` the string start with blank and end with by(which is begin with author)
- `(?<=by\s).*` the author, the rest of whole string

Full code

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

START_URL = 'https://ideas.repec.org/s/fip/fedgfe.html'
page = requests.get(START_URL,verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
datas = []
for paper in soup.findAll("li",class_="list-group-item downfree"):
    data = dict()
    data["date"] = re.findall(r"[-\d]+",paper.text)[0]
    data["Title"] = re.findall(r"(?<=\s).*?(?=by)",paper.text)[0]
    data["Author(s)"] = re.findall(r"(?<=by\s).*",paper.text)[0]
    print(data)
    datas.append(data)
```